# Angular unit testing

Tags: unit-testing

I have this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UserInfoService -> UsersService -> AuthService -> InjectionToken auth0.client -> InjectionToken auth0.client]:            NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken auth0.client!         NullInjectorError:

My spec.ts file:

```
describe('IssuingInformationComponent', () => {
let component: IssuingInformationComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<IssuingInformationComponent>;

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule
             ,AuthModule.forRoot({
            domain: 'dgfgfg',
            clientId: 'fgggfg',
         }),
        ],
     
        declarations: [IssuingInformationComponent],
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IssuingInformationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();

    });
}));`
```

Comment: Your credentials are still in the edit history of the question - make sure you generate a new token immediately.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.